# search engines index html5 web application with nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, indexing

I'm building an html5 web application with knockoutjs + backend rest service in nodejs (custom rest api, I'm not using express and i deliver only json data - no html).

The application is working fine like it is, but I need to get indexed by google.
I populate content using ajax requests and now i need to find a solution to make those pages "visible" for search engines.

Is there any true elegant solution for this? I don't want to make another backend service(website - expressjs or php etc)

Please advice :|

Comment: +1 Interesting question, have you seen http://theothersideofcode.com/what-is-stopping-google-from-indexing-single-page-javascript-applications ? You may have to right some code, but I think it's a viable solution.

Comment: hah, nice post. Actually like this i have to write a lot :) But the idea behind this is cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google specifies a way for your site to provide "HTML snapshots" of ajax-loaded content. Not sure how well this works or if other search engines support it.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started